# How could I fix this CRC error?

Tags: windows-7, crc

How can I solve this CRC data error?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the System Event Log yet?

Comment: In System Event Log I'm getting like "The device, \Device\Harddisk1\DR1, has a bad block." @NateKerkhofs

Answer (score 0):

I would assume hdd failure.
Check it with http://www.hdtune.com/ to find out.
Most important is the "**Health**" report.

Comment: Judging from his screenshot, this would probably be the reason why. His HDD has a bad block.